# How to load facebook page plugin with react

Tags: facebook, reactjs

It is highly ironic that there are no react facebook plugins...

I want to show the facebook page plugin on my site (built in React) but nothing shows.

I have the default javascript jargon (I added `async` to no avail):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.async=true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And the normal page plugin in the `render` of my react component:

```
<div className="fb-page"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/"
    data-tabs="timeline"
    data-width="500"
    data-height="400"
    data-small-header="true"
    data-adapt-container-width="true"
    data-hide-cover="false"
    data-show-facepile="false">
    <blockquote className="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"
                cite="...
</div>
```

How can I get this to load async?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sdk invokes a function after it finished loading the script, called `fbAsyncInit`:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '82195',
        xfbml: false,
        version: 'v2.6'
    });
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event('fb_init'));
};
```

As is show, I dispatch an event when the callback is called; as it indicates that the SDK is loaded. Since the problem is that react loads and executes before the sdk, a listener can be added to the component which can then load the FB plugin when notified:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('fb_init', e => FB.XFBML.parse());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

For example:

```
componentDidMount() {
     FB.XFBML.parse();
}
componentDidUpdate() {
     FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```

Better give it an ID though, or it will check the whole document for Facebook Plugins. Of course you have to make sure that the JavaScript SDK is loaded already, or "FB" will be undefined. You could implement a timer that checks for the availability of "FB" until it´s available (bad idea), or just load the component later - when the JS SDK is loaded for sure.

More information about checking when the JS SDK is loaded: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I tried that but I got `FB is undefined`. I think the js snipped changed that they provide. Can I somehow reach it via `window`?

Comment: take a look at this, works since many years: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: as i wrote in my answer, you have to make sure the js sdk is loaded already. check out window.fbAsyncInit, right after FB.init you can be sure it´s loaded and FB is available.

Comment: That still gives the error. I don't think it [is supported](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/frameworks)

Comment: i am using the js sdk with react since a long time, it is no problem. it is just very important to load the sdk BEFORE using FB.

Comment: just make sure the component is loaded AFTER initializing the JS SDK and it will be fine.

Comment: But how do you do that? The sdk doesn't have a callback?

Comment: it does, check out the link in my comments. i will add it to the question too.